# How to take out the 0 in ggplot (barplot)

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu5sh.png)

When I add the text in the middle of each bar from the plot all the zeros from the dataset appear. I would like to erase these 0 and leave only the numbers but I can't manage to take them out. I am adding a picture and also the code.

```
ia <- ggplot(importance, aes(x = Question, y = quantity))+
  ggtitle("do you consider this area important for you")+
  geom_col(aes(fill = answer), width = 0.7)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=quantity), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5, reverse = TRUE), size=3) +
  xlab("Respondents") + ylab("percentage of respondents")+ 
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7F807F", "#ED7247", "#F3B36B", "#F4FFBE", "#ACE7A5", "#5BC79A"))+ scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)str_wrap(x, width = 18))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
ia
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIMmJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate your data value to NA in order to hide it.
As you did not provide the dataset, I wrote an example with a sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(text="testing",type=c("A","B","C","D","E"),quantity=c(34,22,3,0,1))
df %>% mutate(quantity=ifelse(quantity==0,NA,quantity)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(text,quantity))+geom_col(aes(fill=type))+
  geom_text(aes(label=quantity))+coord_flip()\
```

Use mutate to change zero to NA. I hope this works for your case.

Comment: Hi Marcos, thank you very much for your help! I just added the data frame in my question. I can't manage to use your example with my dataset could you help me for this? Thank you once again I am new with R and am trying to understand how it works

Comment: I can write much code here in comments so try to update your code like this ...ggplot(importance %>% mutate(quantity=ifelse(quantity==0,NA,quantity)), aes(x = Question, y = q... adding this pipe with mutate to change your dataset before input to ggplot

Comment: I hope that worked for you

Comment: Hi Marcos! Thank you so much you are amazing it worked!!! :)

Comment: Great! You can check my answer as accepted. This might help others with similar questions. Have a good one!